# How to config Gedit on osx to edit UTF-8 files

Tags: macos, gedit

I find the `~/.gconf/apps/gedit-2` directory where the `%gconf` file is. But How should i change it so that it use utf-8 as default.

Answer (score 0):

Mac version of GTK, which is used to implement `gedit`, has many issues concerning receiving non-ASCII characters from the keyboard. I don't recommend you to use it if you want to edit general UTF-8 documents with lots of accents and/or Asian characters.

Comment: Textmate's unicode support is not great either. You can't easily input accented characters. There are plugins which allow inputting those characters, but you need to dig into the internets.